# Why does this 7-segment display not light up?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, display, 7segmentdisplay, decoder

> Why this (IC7447 and 7 -Seg combo) not light up?
>   I'm not sure as if what to do of the 3 lines of the IC7447 **(Pin - 3,4,5)** which I've depicted in **GREEN** below. Because at certain sites they have been shown **ACTIVE LOW,** but they are connected to **+Vcc** while many others even don't have connections for them(as seen on YouTube videos.they just leave them isolated).
>   So I'm confused so as what combination of connection to have for them.

IMAGE: With few Discriptions
[image: IC7447 and 7 SEG DISPLAY.PICTORIAL DISCRIPTION]

This is the same IMAGE with adjustment so that wirings will be more clear to see.
[image: DECREASED CONTRAST TO SEE WIRING MORE CLEARLY]
This 7-SEGMENT is for my ELECTRONICS PROJECT of ALU(Arithmetic & LOGIC UNIT),
for 4-bit adder.

Comment: Are none of the segments working or just some of them? Do they light when you attach the wire directly to the supply bypassing the chip?

Comment: None man. None of them are working!

Comment: Yes. i mean when one i directly connect -ve terminal to the other end of resistor(rather than allowing them through IC,)then the segment lights up.

Comment: UPDATE: when i connect the 3rd pin to ground rather than +Vcc(Without disturbing 4th and 5th pin),then the segment shows a Small "b". But The inputs are not showing up. Just a "b" that's it.

Comment: So pin 3 the lamp test pin should make all the segments turn on I believe. Not just b Are your breadboard connections flaky?

Comment: No, my connections are not flaky. And i just got to know that the "b" was due to my broken SEGMENT, the 3rd pin to ground means "lamp test" i.e. to test whether segment is dead or alive.
I now replaced it with a "GOOD" SEGMENT.

However, doing this doesn't solve my problem. No digits on the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the datasheet for a TI family of BCD-to-seven-segment decoders (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5447a.pdf), these control lines are active-low, and should be either left floating or pulled high when not in use (footnotes on p. 3 and 4).

As for the LEDs not lighting up, what input combination have you tried on the decoder? You've left them disconnected on the picture and for all high inputs (=> 15) it outputs a blank display (p. 3)...

(Edit) I see you found that only a few segments light up when you pull pin 3 to ground. That's the Lamp Test Pin, and it should make all the segments light up. If they don't, something is broken. Have you tested all the segments by hand?

Comment: It's only for a 4 bit display(BUT MAX = 7(i.e. 0111)...i guess it may show 15 as well, but in the format "F").
It's just in the picture that I've left them disconnected. Practically i tried various combinations of inputs, but of no use.
Moreover, if i leave them blank, then it should show a 0, isn't it?

Comment: UPDATE: OK FINE, i see that the segment was broken since as i tested one by one, not all of them lit up. Now i changed it and all of them LIT UP. 
But now what,What's next?

Comment: It does not necessarily show '0' when you leave the inputs open, in fact it assumes the inputs are HIGH unless you actively pull them down. Now that you have a working 7-Segment display, try pulling pin 3 (the lamp test) to HIGH again and then apply different combinations of inputs. It should display numbers then (check the table on p. 3 of the datasheet for more details)

Comment: Ok.Cool. It's working now, as you said , It needed me to Actively pull the INPUTS DOWN OR push them UP rather than leaving them disconnected. Even if i had connected one,or two to HIGH and ignored others, even then it was showing blank.
It meant that all Needed to be ACTIVE SOMETHING.
Thanks. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

we have had the same problem as yours..The problem was caused since we had taken a common cathode display..apparently,the problem might be same with your circuit. The 7447 does not work for common cathode display. 7447 only works for a common anode display. So check and verify whether yours is a common anode display. Good Luck! :)
From,
(Agnel Institute of Technology and Design(AITD))